# what is this property? $\int p(x,\pi)d\pi=p(x|E[\pi])$?

Tags: self-study, multinomial-distribution, marginal-distribution, dirichlet-distribution, conjugate-prior

Sorry if the title does not make sense, from the answer of this question [Mistake in derivation about categorical distribution and Dirichlet distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/213277/95569) it can be shown that

say $p(x|\pi)$ follows the categorical distribution (multinomial with one trial), and $p(\pi|\alpha)$ follows the Dirichlet distribution, then

$p(x|\pi)=\prod\pi_i^{x_i}$

$p(\pi|\alpha)=\frac{1}{B(\alpha)}\prod\pi_i^{\alpha_i-1}$

$p(x|\alpha)=\int p(x,\pi|\alpha)d\pi=\frac{B(\alpha+x)}{B(\alpha)}=\prod (\frac{a_i}{\sum a_k})^{x_i}$

$E[\pi_i|\alpha]=\frac{a_i}{\sum a_k}$

$p(x|\alpha)=p(x|E[\pi|\alpha])$, the marginal distribution equals the expected posterior distribution, right?

is this some common property? in what circumstances does it hold?

Thank you.

Comment: Nice property indeed, which I doubt has many equivalent versions outside this Bernoulli setting.

Comment: @Xi'an thanks! yes it seems so. do you think it is because of $\sum x_i=1$? if the $p(x|\pi)$ is changed to multinomial with more than one trials, then $p(x|\alpha)$  doesn't look quite the same.